# Aggregate values of a field by clusters

Tags: qgis, point

I want to group points by distance. I'm using the 'Group of points" in Layer Style.

I also want to sum the value of a field to the aggregate of the cluster, and I need the new cluster point to have the size of the aggregate. Anyone have any idea of how to do it? :D

Comment: check clustering algorithms like dbscan: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html

If you just need symbology, I'd use point cluster in the layer styling options